# Can percentiles of a set of data be calculated in a map-reduce manner?

Tags: java, statistics, mapreduce, percentile

My understanding is to calculate percentiles, the data needs to be sorted.  Would this be possible with a huge amount of data spread across multiple servers, without moving it around?

Answer (score 2):

While MapReduce as a paradigm does not looks suited for the problem, hadoop's implementation of MR - is. 
Hadoop's implementation of map reduce is based on **distributed sort** - and it is what you need. Hadoop is doing sort by moving data  between servers only once - not that bad. 
I would suggest to look onto hadoop terasort implementaiton which illustrate the good (and probabbly the best) way to sort massive data with hadoop. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2):

I would first create a histogram, either on one machine or multiple machines.  Once you have a count for each possible value of buckets of possible values you can combine these if needed. The gain for using a histogram is that it has O(1) insertion/sort time instead of O(log n) and uses O(M) space where M is the number of possible values or buckets instead of O(N) where N is the number of sample.

A histogram is naturally sorted so you can get a total count and find the percentiles by counting from either end.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **yes**, it is *possible*.  But Map-Reduce isn't really designed for this kind of task.  Map-Reduce (as is used in a Hadoop cluster, for instance) shines on unstructured or semi-structured data.  While it has the *ability* to process other kinds, it is not best suited for it.  (I had one project at a company where they wanted to analyze XML in a Hadoop cluster... it wasn't the most fun thing.)

[This scholarly article](http://www.timkaldewey.de/pubs/Clydesdale__EDBT12.pdf) describes some of the issues with Map-Reduce on structured data and offers an alternative approach with "Clydesdale".  (I have never heard of or used this, so I can neither endorse it or speak to its strengths/weaknesses.)

I'm looking for more links that offer explanations and alternatives.